# Base64 encode/decode issue

Tags: openssl, hex, base64, ocaml

I have two functions to convert to and from base64 using openssl:

```
 (* base64 encode *)
 let encode_base64 msg =
   let open_ssl_arg = "echo -n '" ^ msg ^ "' | openssl enc -base64" in
   let ic = Unix.open_process_in open_ssl_arg in
   let rec output s =
     try let new_line = input_line ic in output (s ^ new_line);
     with End_of_file -> s
   in
  Unix.close_process_in |> fun _ -> ();
  output ""

(* base64 decode *)
let decode_base64 msg =
  let open_ssl_arg = "echo -n '" ^ msg ^ "' | base64 -d" in
  let ic = Unix.open_process_in open_ssl_arg in
  let rec output s =
    try let new_line = input_line ic in output (s ^ new_line);
    with End_of_file -> s
  in
  Unix.close_process_in |> fun _ -> ();
  output ""
```

These seem to work fine. I can test them with something like:

```
 # decode_base64 @@ encode_base64 "HelloWorld";;
 - : string = "HelloWorld"
```

As part of an API interface I am building I need to be able to base64 decode a secret key.

When I try this same test with the secret key provided by the API I receive the following message:

```
 encode_base64 @@ decode_base64 secret_key;;
 /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string                            
 - : string = ""
```

I can decode the secret key fine, but when I put the decoded secret key string back into the encode_base64 function I receive the error. I cannot see what I am doing wrong, but I think the problem must be in the decode function because I have been using the encode function in many other API interfaces with no problem.

Also I know that my secret key is not the problem because I can perform all functions just fine in python with the same secret key. Could this be an Oct vs Hex string formatting issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

openssl is writing the base64 text with embedded newlines every 64 chars.  That means that your input to `echo -n` inside `decode_base64` has newlines in it.  This gives you the "Unterminated quoted string" message.

This is a crazy way to be doing base64 encoding in OCaml anyway.  Check out https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-base64

Comment: I was not aware of this library, thanks for the info.